# Modify EXIF Data using C++

Tags: c++, camera, gps, latitude-longitude, exif

We are building a quad copter robot for a competition, and one of the requirements is that we have to capture photos using the camera that is installed on the quad copter.

I wrote a simple OpenCV program that is able to capture them in .jpg format, but my camera or my program are unable to save "latitude" and "longitude" as EXIF on my images.

I've added to my robot a GPS module that can retrieve GPS data while capturing photos and save them to a text file.

So my main problem is adding these data from the text file to the pictures separately while they are captured.

I tried many libraries like:

- easyexif
- Exiv2
- Phil Harvey

Also I tried them in:

- Visual C++ .net 2015
- Dev C++ (GCC)
- Code Blocks (GCC)

and also I worked on PHP but I just can read and extract EIXFs but I can't write new data on my pictures.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: *I tried many libraries like: - easyexif - Exiv2 and Phil Harvey* -- And what was the problem with these libraries?

Comment: What format are the images you want to manipulate?

Comment: Hi Dear Paul, the images have .jpg format.

Comment: this link has a complete example about adding data to image using exiv2 :[exiv2 example](http://www.exiv2.org/examples.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, But I do not know in Example 2: addmoddel.cpp where my image(s) calls for modifying?

Comment: Hi again, at this link http://pay24.ir/upload/upload_files/exif_modify.zip I upload my project. could you please tell me how should I call image?

Comment: Can you update this thread? Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code. I used [Image::GetPropertyIdList method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-constant-property-item-descriptions) and [Reading and Writing Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-image-getpropertyidlist) as a material for this code. unfortunately i didnt find any function in opencv that can manipulate Exif.

```
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <gdiplus.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <Math.h>
 #pragma comment(lib,"gdiplus.lib")
 using namespace Gdiplus;


 int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid) //i copy this function from Doc.microsoft.com
 {
UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
if (size == 0)
    return -1;  // Failure

pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
    return -1;  // Failure

GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
{
    if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0)
    {
        *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
        free(pImageCodecInfo);
        return j;  // Success
    }
}

free(pImageCodecInfo);
return -1; }


int main(){
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
Status stat;
CLSID  clsid;

Bitmap* bitmap = new Bitmap(L"Source.bmp"); // you can use any Image Format as Source 
PropertyItem* propertyItem = new PropertyItem;
// Get the CLSID of the JPEG encoder.
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);

double dlan = 35.715298; // we supposed that your GPS data is Double if its not skip this step
// convert double to unsigned long array
double coord = dlan;
int sec = (int)round(coord * 3600);
int deg = sec / 3600;
sec = abs(sec % 3600);
int min = sec / 60;
sec %= 60;
unsigned long ulExifCoordFormatLan[6] = { deg, 1, min, 1, sec, 1 };
propertyItem->id = PropertyTagGpsLatitude;
propertyItem->length = sizeof(long) * 2 * 3;
propertyItem->type = PropertyTagTypeRational;
propertyItem->value = ulExifCoordFormatLan;
Status s = bitmap->SetPropertyItem(propertyItem);// saving image to the destination

stat = bitmap->Save(L"Dest.jpg", &clsid, NULL);
if (s == Ok && stat==Ok)
    printf("Dest.jpg saved successfully .\n");

delete propertyItem;
delete bitmap;
GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
return 0;}
```